# link MKL libraries in Windows / Clion /Cmake

Tags: cmake, clion, intel-mkl

I am very new in CMake and I am trying to include MKL libraries in my project done in Clion.
Compiler is MVS 2019 as required.

Using [MKL tool](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.html) I get the following information:

```
use this link line:  mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib mkl_tbb_thread_dll.lib mkl_core_dll.lib tbb.lib
compiler options:  /DMKL_ILP64 -I"%MKLROOT%"\include
```

My best knowledge of CMake allowed me to try the following:

```
set(MKL_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2020.3.279/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win")
target_link_libraries(project_x PRIVATE "${MKL_DIR}/mkl_intel_lp64")
```

but of course when I tried to check if it finds the library:

```
find_library(MKL_LIB mkl_intel_lp64)
if(NOT MKL_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "mkl library not found")
endif()
```

the results are disappointing (=edit:library could not be found). How can I properly do this in Windows / Clion IDE?

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what do you mean by "the results are disappointing"? Unfortunately, there is no official FindMKL.cmake or MKLConfig.cmake exists so far. The current state of this described here https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20479

Comment: Sorry for my figure of speech. I meant that the library just cannot be found. Thanks for the link I will try to investigate.

Comment: That's actually very sad when you understand that your problem runs unsolved for many years around the community...Is there any alternatives, what could be my options (just need to avoid using MVS2019 itself as IDE)