# How to build MKL with Cmake and mingw on Windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, cmake, mingw-w64, intel-mkl

I am trying to build a C-project where I use the Math Kernel Library (MKL) by Intel to accelerate matrix multiplication as follows:

```
#define MKL
#ifdef MKL
    #include <mkl.h>
#endif
void gemm_cpu(int TA, int TB, int M, int N, int K, float ALPHA, float *A, int lda, float *B, int ldb, float BETA, float *C, int ldc)
{
#ifdef MKL
    if (!TA && !TB)
        cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, BETA, C, ldc);
    else if (TA && !TB)
        cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, CblasNoTrans, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, BETA, C, ldc);
    else if (!TA && TB)
        cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, BETA, C, ldc);
    else
        cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, CblasTrans, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, BETA, C, ldc);
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < N * M; ++i)
        C[i] *= BETA;
    if (!TA && !TB)
        gemm_nn(M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, C, ldc);
    else if (TA && !TB)
        gemm_tn(M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, C, ldc);
    else if (!TA && TB)
        gemm_nt(M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, C, ldc);
    else
        gemm_tt(M, N, K, ALPHA, A, lda, B, ldb, C, ldc);
#endif
}
```

I am on Windows 10 with CLion as IDE and using gcc.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.2.0 as a compiler. Unfortunately, my build fails and cannot link MKL. My cmake for building MKL is as follows:

```
# The Mkl has to be installed locally
set(external_folder "D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/project/external")
set(mkl_dir "${external_folder}/mkl")

# link options provided by https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor
message(STATUS "[MKL] MKL path: ${mkl_dir}.")

# 64bits
set(mkl_libraries
        "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64.lib"
        "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64/mkl_core.lib"
        "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64/mkl_sequential.lib"
        )

set(mkl_dlls
        "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib"
        "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64/mkl_core_dll.lib"
        "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64/mkl_sequential_dll.lib"
        )


add_library(mkl INTERFACE)
add_compile_definitions(MKL_LP64)
add_compile_definitions(function=cblas_sgemm)

target_link_directories(mkl INTERFACE "${mkl_dir}/lib/intel64")
target_link_libraries(mkl INTERFACE ${mkl_dlls})
target_include_directories(mkl INTERFACE "${mkl_dir}/include")

## install mkl libs
INSTALL(FILES ${mkl_libraries} DESTINATION lib)

# Also install the dll on windows
install(FILES ${mkl_dlls} DESTINATION lib)
```

I tried different configurations for my Cmake file but I always keep getting `undefined reference to ..` errors like this one:

```
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.text[sgemm]+0x219): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.text[sgemm]+0x37c): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.xdata+0x3c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.text[sgemm_64]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.text[sgemm_64]+0x2fc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_sgemm_lp64.obj):(.xdata+0x3c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_printf_s]+0x54): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfprintf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_fprintf_s]+0x78): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_fprintf_s]+0xb8): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_fprintf_stdout_s]+0x54): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfprintf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_vfprintf_s]+0x2e): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfprintf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_vfprintf_stdout_s]+0x38): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfprintf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_sprintf_s]+0x5f): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_sprintf_char_s]+0x65): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_vsprintf_s]+0x43): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_vsnprintf_s]+0x48): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_snprintf_s]+0x5e): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_sscanf_s]+0x54): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vsscanf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_fscanf_s]+0x46): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfscanf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_vfprintf_stderr_s]+0x38): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfprintf'
D:/wecode_build_tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Users/superkogito/Desktop/workspace/cpp/audio_framework_v2/plugin/my_plugins/ImGuiExample/external/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(mkl_libc.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_fprintf_stderr_s]+0x54): undefined reference to `__stdio_common_vfprintf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This seems due to the incompatibility between MKL and mingw as referenced in the following links:

- [link MKL libraries in Windows / Clion /Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486436/link-mkl-libraries-in-windows-clion-cmake)
- https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-linking-with-MinGW64-is-it-still-impossible/m-p/1155228

but I was hoping that someone has a patch or maybe since I only need `cblas_sgemm`, I might be able to build around the incompatibilities. I mainly need to avoid using Visual Studio so if there is a way around it, I would like to hear it.

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to build the project with **MinGW** but use libraries built for **Visual Studio**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161814/warning-corrupt-drectve-at-end-of-def-file.

Comment: yeah, that sounds right. There are some attempts to combine both [1](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-linking-with-MinGW64-is-it-still-impossible/td-p/1155228) and [2](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-with-MinGW64-compiler/m-p/802929) but without any confirmation if it works. Also since MKL source is closed, I cannot build from source, so I was hoping for a patch or confirmation that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Also since MKL source is closed, I cannot build from source, so I was hoping for a patch or confirmation that it is not possible.

I don't see anything in the documentation implying any sort of support for `MinGW`. Looks like the only supported platforms are Windows, Linux, and MacOS.

> I mainly need to avoid using Visual Studio so if there is a way around it, I would like to hear it.

I'd consider using `Visual Studio Code` it's been absolutely lovely for cross-platform CMake C++ development.

But since you are already using `clion` it's worth pointing out you can use the MSVC toolchain with CLion:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC

This will allow you to be compatible with the `pre-built` Windows binaries provided by Intel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was resolved using `mkl_rt.lib` and adding to PATH where
`mkl_rt.dll` (`mkl_rt.2.dll`) and `libiomp5md.dll`. As I remember they are in the different places.
It works but it seems that `mkl_rt` has some limited performance.